# Zend Framework Error : The requested URL was not found

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up my zend framework application on this host but I'm getting a Requested URL not found error:

The application isn't at the root level i.e its in a folder like: www.mysite.com/zendapp/public

The error says that it can't locate the index.php file even though the url given in the erro message is correct.

Is this an htaccess issue? The homepage opens fine - the issue arises when I click on any link. Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

URL rewrite is enabled on the host.

Comment: Where are the links pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) in your .htaccess
2. [`baseUrl` property](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.baseurl) of the front controller

Comment: WHere do I set the baseUrl here and in my case what would it be. Can teh base Url be set in the application.ini file as well?

Comment: `resources.frontController.baseUrl = /path/to/project`. Please read the documentation, everything is there and I already provided a link, so minimal search required.